# Mathematica gets stuck trying to solve a simple differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear, boundary-conditions

I reach a dead end when trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$1+x-x^2=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Bigg\{\frac{2}{y(x)}\bigg[1+\bigg(\frac{1+0.001x}{2y(x)}\bigg)^2\bigg]^{-1}\Bigg\}$$

I use DSolve for this, with the boundary condition $y(0)=0$:

```
DSolve[{1 + x - x^2 == D[2/(y[x]*(((1 + 0.001*x)/(2*y[x]))^2 + 1)), {x}], y[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

For some reason, Mathematica gets stuck trying to calculate this, without obtaining any answer at all. The problem is clearly with the $(1+0.001x)$ part of the equation, because if I change this into simply $x$, meaning I solve the following equation:

$$1+x-x^2=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Bigg\{\frac{2}{y(x)}\bigg[1+\bigg(\frac{x}{2y(x)}\bigg)^2\bigg]^{-1}\Bigg\}$$

```
DSolve[{1 + x - x^2 == D[2/(y[x]*((x/(2*y[x]))^2 + 1)), {x}], y[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

It yields a solution within seconds.

Even if I get rid of the small floating number $0.001$, which intuitively seems to be the cause of the mishap, and simply replace it with $(1+x)$, it still gets stuck trying to return an answer.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not get stuck, it returns right away

```
ClearAll[x,y]
z=1/1000;
DSolve[{1+x-x^2==D[2/(y[x]*(((1+ z x)/(2*y[x]))^2+1)),{x}],y[0]==0},y[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But your input makes it stuck

```
ClearAll[x,y]
z=0.001;
DSolve[{1+x-x^2==D[2/(y[x]*(((1+ z x)/(2*y[x]))^2+1)),{x}],y[0]==0},y[x],x]
```

As a general rules, use exact input with symbolic functions like `DSolve`, always safer.

**To answer comment**

You can see why it does not like `y[0]=0`

```
ClearAll[x, y, a]
z = 1/1000;
sol = y[x] /. 
  First@DSolve[{1 + x - x^2 == 
      D[2/(y[x]*(((1 + z x)/(2*y[x]))^2 + 1)), {x}], y[0] == a}, y[x],
     x]

sol2 = Limit[sol, a -> 0];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now at `x=0` the above is

```
sol2/.x->0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you boundary condition `y[0]=0` leads to a problem. May be this is why `DSolve` is having trouble with this. Changing the boundary conditions so it is little away from zero, now `DSolve` gives solution (not shown)

```
sol=y[x]/.First@DSolve[{1+x-x^2==D[2/(y[x]*(((1+z x)/(2*y[x]))^2+1)),
       {x}],y[0]==1/1000000},y[x],x]
```

Basically, your boundary condition at `x=0` does not seem to be consistent with the ODE. But may be more analysis is needed, this is just a quick look.

---

**update**

Thanks to comment by bbgodfrey, changing `sol2/.x->0` above by `Limit[sol2,x->0]` gives `0` instead of `Indeterminate`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But while you're right that it doesn't get stuck with exact input, it returns a blank output line...

Comment: Ok, if I get rid of the boundary condition $y[0]==0$, I get an answer. Anybody knows why this is happening?

Comment: Try `Limit[sol2, x -> 0]` instead of `sol2/.x->0` to obtain `0`, as desired.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks. Updated per your comment.

Answer (score 5):

The solution of the ODE without a boundary condition is

```
s = y[x] /. DSolve[1 + x - x^2 == D[2/(y[x]*(((1 + x z)/(2*y[x]))^2 + 1)), x], y[x], x]
(* {(-384 - √(147456 - 4 (-192 x - 96 x^2 + 64 x^3 - 12 C[1]) (-48 x - 24 x^2 + 
     6 x^3 - 96 x^2 z - 48 x^3 z + 32 x^4 z - 48 x^3 z^2 - 24 x^4 z^2 + 16 x^5 z^2 - 
     3 C[1] - 6 x z C[1] - 3 x^2 z^2 C[1])))/(2 (-192 x - 96 x^2 + 64 x^3 - 12 C[1])), 
    (-384 + √(147456 - 4 (-192 x - 96 x^2 + 64 x^3 - 12 C[1]) (-48 x - 24 x^2 + 
     16 x^3 - 96 x^2 z - 48 x^3 z + 32 x^4 z - 48 x^3 z^2 - 24 x^4 z^2 + 16 x^5 z^2 - 
     3 C[1] - 6 x z C[1] - 3 x^2 z^2 C[1])))/(2 (-192 x - 96 x^2 + 64 x^3 - 12 C[1]))} *)
```

Now consider the values of both solutions of `y` at `x == 0`.

```
Simplify[s /. x -> 0]
(* {(32 + Sqrt[1024 - C[1]^2])/(2 C[1]), -((-32 + Sqrt[1024 - C[1]^2])/(2 C[1]))} *)
```

The first clearly cannot equal zero for any value of the constant `C[1]`.  However,

```
Series[Last@%, {C[1], 0, 3}] // Normal    
(* C[1]/128 + C[1]^3/524288 *)
```

So, `C[1] == 0` causes the second solution for `y[x]` to vanish at the origin.

```
Plot[Last[s /. {C[1] -> 0, z -> 1/1000}], {x, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold, Black]]
```

[image]

Evidently, `DSolve` did not recognize this.  It is not uncommon for `DSolve` to have difficulties applying boundary conditions.

**Addendum**

Another way to see that the ODE is well behaved near `y[0] == 0` is to expand the ODE at `x == 0` and solve for higher-order derivatives.   For instance,

```
Solve[Thread[CoefficientList[(Series[1 + x - x^2 - D[2/(y[x]*(((1 + z*x)/
    (2*y[x]))^2 + 1)), x], {x, 0, 2}] // Normal) /. y[0] -> 0, x] == 0], 
    {y'[0], y''[0], y'''[0]}]
(* {{Derivative[1][y][0] -> 1/8, 
     Derivative[2][y][0] -> (1 + 4*z)/8, 
     Derivative[3][y][0] -> (-13 + 48*z + 48*z^2)/64}} *)
```

It also is possible to integrate the ODE numerically with `NDSolve`, although some care must be taken, because the ODE is singular at `x == 0`, even though its solution is not.

Comment: That really helped, thanks!